# Installing Fuerte on 8.04 (or running Fuerte on a 2.6.24 kernel)

Tags: ros-fuerte, ubuntu

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am having quite a difficult time using ROS with to peices of hardware, specifically the Novint Falcon and a set of Schunk Powercubes.

In order to use the Falcon drivers I must run Ubuntu 10.04 or later. On this system, I am using ROS Fuerte.

On another system that I want to communicate with, I aim to use the Powercubes through ESD's CAN-USB-Mini. The drivers for this device support kernels 2.6.24 and lower, but in order to communicate with my computer connected to the Falcon I must use Fuerte.

Is there any way I can install Fuerte on Ubuntu 8.04?

Can I communicate between Fuerte and Box Turtle?

Will Fuerte run if I am able to downgrade my kernel to 2.6.24

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/85486/installing-fuerte-on-8.04-(or-running-fuerte-on-a-2.6.24-kernel)/) by [MWrock](https://answers.ros.org/users/7271/mwrock/) on ROS Answers with karma: 15 on 2013-09-30

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can install Fuerte from source on an older Ubuntu.  Though you will also probably need to upgrade system libraries from source as well to make sure you have the minimum version requirements.  It will be a lot of work to get it to work.  It will take a lot of time and patience.  *I do not recommend it, and would not attempt it myself.*

Fuerte and Boxturtle are very far apart.  Communications between different versions of ROS may work in certain situations.

Downgrading the kernel is likely your best approach. Not all subsystems will work but I know of others who have used older kernels to talk to a Falcon from a lucid machine.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2013-10-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0